# Calculating the measurement of the arc of a circle with a triangle inside

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOUSV.png)

Hello,

I've been trying to understand the solution to the problem above. I am confused as to how the solution can declare that angle DQE = (arc BC + arc DE)/2 and angle CPQ = (arc CD - arc BC)/2. I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) That's a generalization of Thales Theorem known as the inscribed angle theorem.